# Default shipping in cart

Tags: cart, shipping

Thats how I understand the problem:

Magento cant show a default shipping value in cart to guests or not-logged-in users because it doesnt know the country from a standard shipping address, right?

I only have one country to ship to (even only one global price) so it would be great if I could set that for everyone to see the shipping costs in cart even if guest or not-logged-in.

Is this right and can it be done? :)

Thx

EDIT: I mean the real costs in totals section -> NOT estimate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write an extension for it. I modified and used a small extension written long time ago. You can try it out if it works. The link of the extension is [Default shipping](http://www.rapidcommerce.eu/blog/2012/04/allways-show-shipping-costs-in-magento/)

Comment: awesome bro :) this will at least give me the needed hints to get this done if not working directly!

Comment: glad i could help :) cheers !!!